# Can Silverlight hook into the browser's Edit > Cut/Copy/Paste menu items?

Tags: silverlight, browser, copy-paste

We have a Silverlight app that contains a grid, and we've added support for selecting multiple cells, copying their contents to the clipboard, and pasting back elsewhere in the grid. Currently the user invokes the Copy and Paste commands by either clicking a toolbar button inside our Silverlight app, or using the standard keyboard shortcuts, which we catch with a KeyDown event.

Is it possible to also hook into the browser's native Edit menu, and the Cut, Copy, Paste, etc. menu items that are built into the browser? For example, can the user drop down the Firefox button (or press Alt+E to drop down the classic Edit menu), click the Copy item in Firefox's menu, and have some sort of Copy command be relayed to the focused control in my Silverlight app? Same thing for the equivalent menus in IE, Chrome, Opera, etc.

I wouldn't be surprised if this can't be done, since even long-established browser plug-ins like Adobe Reader have their own buttons for copy/paste and even print, rather than hooking into the browser's native menus. But I've never programmed to a browser's plug-in model, so I don't know for sure what's possible.

Comment: Good question. I'm also dubious whether this is possible, but it would surely be nice in terms of user experience,